# Cmake count occurences of words in a file

Tags: cmake

I know this sounds totally weird ... but a new requirement came up and we need to count the occurrences of a specific word in all our C++ files, using CMake (specifically in a platform independent way, not assuming we have any other tools, such as python, perl,)...

Is this even remotely possible? If yes, How?

Answer (score 4):

```
FILE(READ file.cpp contents)
STRING(REGEX MATCHALL needle matches "${contents}")
```

Now `matches` will be a list of all the occurrences of `needle` in `file.cpp`.

If, like requested in the question title, you also need to count the number of occurrencies, you would then  call:
[`list(LENGTH matches n_matches)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/list.html).